# Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: callout, calloutexception

after sending http request from the anonymous apex

```java
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
httpRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
httpRequest.setHeader('Content-Length', 'calculated when request is sent');
httpRequest.setHeader('Host', 'calculated when request is sent');
httpRequest.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');

httpRequest.setBody('{"grant_type":"' + X + '", ' +
                        '"client_id":"' + XX + '", ' +
                        '"client_secret":"' + XXX + '"}');

httpRequest.setEndPoint(loginEndPointURL);
httpRequest.setMethod('POST');
httpRequest.setTimeout(10000);

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);
```

I catch this error in last line HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);

```
Error on line 46, column 1: System.CalloutException: Unexpected end of file from server
Class.X.GXX: line 46, column 1
AnonymousBlock: line 1, column 1
AnonymousBlock: line 1, column 1
```

When I comment setHeader.Host - I catch an Unautorized answer from the server.
***From postmen - all work well with 4 same headers (one difference is that in PostMan - Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded). The endpoint is predefined.

***Thx for any idea.***

Comment: At a glance, I don't think you want to set your Host or Content-Length. Setting them explicitly in your code may cause problems when Salesforce should automatically fill them in. What happens if you set the Content-Type to "application/json" in Postman? This definitely looks like only JSON and `x-www-form-urlencoded` doesn't necessary match. But a lot of HTTP software depending on the destination can handle requests even if the Content-Type is inaccurate.

Comment: @nbrown Thx for your answer.
1) If I use application/x-www-form-urlencoded - i get {
    "error": {
        "message": "Unauthorized",
        "correlationId": "hiden",
        "issuedAt": "2020-12-14T20:36:02.791Z",
        "errorCode": "Unauthorized"
    }
}